# How to generate testng report without overwritng the previous test result

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml

I am automating Web Application using Selenium with Java.

I am executing multiple testng xml files in parallel, so the result gets overridden every time.

Eg: I have two xml files (testng1.xml and testng 2.xml). When I run these two files in parallel, result from testng2.xml is override with testng1.xml in the emailable report.

How to generate a separate report for each xml file?

Comment: run your tests on a *build server*, e.g. `jenkins`, it will keep the results for you...

Comment: Is it possible in Maven...? If yes, can you please guide me how to achieve.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this scenario by using the below code.

```
public String xmlString;

public int xmlIndex;

public String folderName;

public String locationName;

public static String reportName = "emailable-report.html";

    xmlString = <list of xml files>;
    xmlIndex = xmlString.lastIndexOf("/");
    locationName = xmlString.substring(xmlIndex+1);
    folderName = locationName.replace(".xml", "").toUpperCase();

File dir = new File("Result"); // Here I am creating a common folder and the sub folders will be created as per the xml file executions.
    if(dir.exists())
    {
        try {
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    else
    {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    String xmlFolderPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/"+ dir + "/"+ folderName;
    testng.setOutputDirectory(xmlFolderPath);
    File resultFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/"+ dir + "/" +"ResultFiles"); // In this folder only testng result (.html)files are moved here.
    resultFile.mkdir();


File folder = new File(xmlFolderPath); // In this folder, separate sub folders were created according to the xml files and the sub folder will be the xml file names. 
     File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
        {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
          {                   
              if(reportName.equalsIgnoreCase("emailable-report.html"))       
              {                   
                  Path src = Paths.get(xmlFolderPath + "/" + reportName);
                  Path desc = Paths.get(resultFile + "/" + folderName + ".html"); // Here emailable-report.html is renamed according to the XML file name and moved to this folder
                  try
                  {
                    Files.move(src, desc, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    System.out.println(src.resolveSibling(folderName + ".html"));
                    break;
                  } 
                  catch (IOException e) 
                  {
                    System.out.println(e);
                  }
             }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println("Expected file not present in the specified folder..!!!");
              }
          }
        }
```